# Bundler can't find gem bundler/bower

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler, osx-elcapitan

Environment:

- Mac OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)
- Homebrew 0.9.5
- rvm 1.26.11 (same problem occurs with rbenv)
- Bundler 1.11.2

Gemfile (excerpt):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
require 'bundler/bower'

asset "jquery", "~2.1.4"`
```

I get this error:

```
bundle install

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:
cannot load such file -- bundler/bower. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/nobby/becompany/website/src/website-static/Gemfile:5
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  require 'bundler/bower'
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

My RubyGems environment is:

```
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1
- RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin15]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nobby/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/nobby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/nobby/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/nobby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-15
- GEM PATHS:
    - /Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
    - /Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
    - /Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin
    - /Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin
    - /Users/nobby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin
    - /Users/nobby/.rvm/bin
    - /Users/nobby/src/apache/ant/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /sbin
```

Maybe bundler is looking in the wrong gem paths? Is there a way to see which paths it is using?

---

It works when I manually add the dependencies to LOAD_PATH in Gemfile; maybe this helps to point me to the cause of the problem:

```
[ 'bundler-bower-0.0.3', 'bower-rails-0.10.0'].each do |dep|
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift "/Users/nobby/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/#{dep}/lib"
end
```

Comment: what's the output of `bundle show bundler-bower --path`

Comment: When I run `bundle show bundler-bower --paths` I get the same error: `cannot load such file -- bundler/bower`.

Comment: Just do a `bundle show` and see if bundler-bower is their

Comment: `bundle show` results in the same error message.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/LTe/bundler-bower

You need to

```
gem install 'bundler-bower'
```

before you can require modules from it. Potentially (hopefully) bundler is clever enough to resolve dependency order if you add

```
gem 'bundler-bower'
```

to your gemfile and then install it with
    bundle install
instead

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks a lot for your reply. I had already run `gem install 'bundler-bower'` successfully. Adding `gem 'bundler-bower'` unfortunately doesn't seem to help, I still get the same error.